# Timeout handling with node.js stream piping

Tags: node.js, error-handling, stream, timeout, pipe

I'm piping to a file an HTTPS request, it works ok 99.9% of calls, but occasionally (maybe when server or network are not available) hangs indefinitely...

This obviously cause my application to stop working and requiring a manual restart...

I have other https connections that used to occasionally hang that always complete now using the following error code on the request object, as suggested on node documentation:

```
request.on('socket', function(socket) {
    socket.setTimeout(10000);
    socket.on('timeout', function() { request.abort(); });
});

request.on('error', function(e) {
   // Handle the error...
   console.error("FAILED!");
});
```

... but it seems that timeouts on the request are ignored if the destination is piped to a file stream, maybe I should handle an error with a timeout on the filesystem object, but the documentation is not clear if there is an event I have to wait for except for 'finish'...

Here is the sample code, I hope someone can help me:

```
var https = require('https'),
    fs = require('fs');

var opts = {
        host: 'www.google.com',
        path: '/',
        method: 'GET',
        port: 443
};

var file = fs.createWriteStream('test.html');

var request = https.request(opts, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function() {
        file.close(function(){
            console.log("OK!");
        });
    });
 });

request.on('socket', function(socket) {
    socket.setTimeout(10000);
    socket.on('timeout', function() { request.abort(); });
});

request.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error("FAILED!");
});

request.end();
```

If you wanna try the hang, change *host* and *path* with a huge file and disconnect the network cable during the transfer, it should time out after 10 seconds, but it doesn't...

Answer (score 2):

I set up a demo node.js http server that sends a very slow answer and a client similar to your sample code.

When I start the client and then stop the server while sending the response then I also don't get a `timeout` event on the socket but I get a `end` event on the response within the client:

```
var request = https.request(opts, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function() {
        file.close(function(){
           console.log("OK!");
        });
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
       // this is printed when I stop the server
       console.log("response ended");
    });
 });
```

```

Maybe you could listen to that event?

Comment: The problem is that 'end' got emitted also when the tansfer ends, not only when it's interrupted or timed out, I need a way to detect errors.